# Can we use thread inside [STAThread] main?

Tags: c#, .net

when we use `STAThread` in the `Main`, does it mean we cannot create new thread from `Main`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Most UI applications start in an STA thread - it doesn't stop them from starting new threads. `STAThread` is mostly about COM interop. I've found you can *mostly* ignore it when you're not using anything that uses COM - but be aware that UI controls which interact with the clipboard etc may well use COM.

Note that the attribute just affects the apartment model for the newly created thread which runs the application. It's got very little to do with the `Main` method itself, really - it could have been an assembly attribute, or something like that instead.

Comment: What is the default thread model if I didnot specify anything?

Comment: @AdamLee: "Unknown", I believe. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.getapartmentstate.aspx